# typescript typings error when using es6-shim Promise.all()

Tags: typescript, es6-promise, typescript-typings

**Problem**
The typescript compiler appears to be incorrectly issuing a type error for Promise.all().

In particular, it appears that either:

- the typings for Promise.all() within **es6-shim** are incorrect
- or, the typescript compiler isn't interpreting those typings correctly

I looked over the typings for Promise in es6-shim, but they appear to be correct to me. In particular, it seems like this is the line that is being misinterpreted:

```
interface PromiseConstructor {
    all<T>(values: IterableShim<T | PromiseLike<T>>): Promise<T[]>;
}
```

and perhaps resolving to type: `Promise<PromiseLike<T>[]>`
instead of a Promise returning an array of (non-Promise) values.

**To Reproduce**
OSX: El Capitan 10.11.6
node: v4.4.7
typescript: 1.8.10
typings: 1.3.2

I set up a minimal example, by clearing my typings directory, and running:

```
typings install dt~es6-shim --save --global
```

Then I created a test file, t.ts:

```
/// <reference path="typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts" />
export function seedTestDatabase() : Promise<boolean[]> {
    type BP = Promise<boolean>
    var promises: BP[] = []
    var bp: BP = Promise.resolve(true)
    promises.push(bp)
    promises.push(Promise.resolve(true))
    var p = Promise.all(promises)
    return p
}
```

and I compiled this by:

```
tsc --module commonjs t.ts
```

which produces the error:

```
t.ts(9,12): error TS2322: Type 'Promise<Promise<boolean>[]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<boolean[]>'.  
Type 'Promise<boolean>[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean[]'.  
Type 'Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Note: the code returns a Promise resolving to an array of values, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which version of TS are you using ?

It appears to be that bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10143

It's fixed in TS 2.0 beta.

Comment: typescript: 1.8.10

Comment: Thanks, I updated to typescript@beta (=2.0.0), and the compiler error no longer appears.